# I included Blazor component to my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project but it doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

[image]It displays but doesn't work button click.

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<component type="typeof(ShiftsEditor)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"/>
</body>
</html>
```

ShiftsEditor.razor (it is the test component):

```
@page "/ShiftsEditor"

<h3>ShiftsEditor</h3>
<p>@prgf</p>
<button @onclick="UpdateHeading">button</button>

@code {
    public string prgf = "str";

    public void UpdateHeading() => prgf = "content updated";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the JS you are referencing in `_Layout.cshtml` is `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` or
`<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`.

`server.js` needs to use `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"`, and `webassembly.js` needs to use `render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"`.

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(ShiftsEditor)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Add`@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` and `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` in razor.

ShiftsEditor.razor:

```
@page "/ShiftsEditor"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

<h3>ShiftsEditor</h3>
<p>@prgf</p>
<button @onclick="UpdateHeading">button</button>
@code {
    public string prgf = "str";
    public void UpdateHeading() => prgf = "content updated";
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<base href="~/" />
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Program：

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
}
```

Test Result:

Before click:

[image]

After click:

[image]

Comment: I haven't file _Layout.cshtml

Comment: In "Views/Shared".It should be here.